# (Exception in thread "main" org.json) A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1

Tags: java, json

I've been troubles to read my json file in the directory: E:\1PROGRAMMING\Padlock\src\padlock\register\info.json

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "Email": "3",
      "Second Name": "2",
      "Age": "123",
      "Name": "1",
      "Password": "4"
    }
  ]
}
```

The problem is that every time i try to read my content file as json object i recieve an error like the post's title.
The main idea is to read this json file to add a new user in the "users" array inside my json object and create a basic local users database.

```
private static void  SignUp() throws IOException, JSONException, ParseException {
        //System.out.println("SignUp");
        String path = "E:\\1PROGRAMMING\\Padlock\\src\\padlock\\register\\info.json";
        String[] labels = {"Age","Name","Second Name","Email","Password"};
        ArrayList<String> dataUser = new ArrayList<>();

      
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        //check if value Integer
        System.out.println(labels[0]);
        int age = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());

        if( age >= 18) {
            dataUser.add(Integer.toString(age)); //adding age data to arraylist as first data

            for (int element =1;element< labels.length;element++){ //adding rest of data
                System.out.println(labels[element]);
                String data = scanner.nextLine();
                dataUser.add(data);
            }
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //Spring data request to Python serverless
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////

            System.out.println(dataUser);

            //Add to JSON file
            File exists = new File(path);
            if (exists.exists()) {//check if json exists
                System.out.println("File found.");
                //addToJson()
                addToJson(path, dataUser); //HERE IS THE PROBLEM
            }else{
                System.out.println("File not found... Creating File with the new user");
                //createJson()
                createJson(path, dataUser, labels);
                //createJson(path, name, secondName,age,email,password);
            }
        }else {
            System.out.println("You must be more than 18 years old.");
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }
```

And the addToJson function where i want to read and edit my file

```
private static void addToJson(String path, ArrayList<String> dataUser) throws IOException, ParseException, JSONException {
        //create jsonobject to add in our path file
        
        //read path file content
        JSONObject ar = new JSONObject(path);

        for (int i = 0; i < ar.length(); i++) {
            System.out.println( "Name: " + ar.getString("Password") );
        }
        
        //Add jsonobject created into our path file

    }
```

And it plots this error message:

** Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 of E:\1PROGRAMMING\Padlock\src\padlock\register\info.json **

Comment: have posted an answer, let me know if it worked for u.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be that it reads my josn file as String and it locates "[" in the wrong index but  i need to find the way that i can read it as Json element or access directly to the "users" jsonArray inside of it

Answer (score 0):

Your `JSON` is correct , you can verify at https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#

The problem is at line

```
JSONObject ar = new JSONObject(path);
```

since your variable `path` is of type `String` JSONObject doesnt know if its a path to a `.json` file hence its trying to parse the `<file Location>` into JSON and you are getting an `JSONParseException`
hence the error, try this

```
String text = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName)),StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get("e:/info.json");
        Map<Long, User> users = loadUsers(path);
        signUp(users);
        saveUsers(path, users);
    }

    public static Map<Long, User> loadUsers(Path path) throws IOException {
        JSONObject root = readRootObject(path);
        Map<Long, User> users = new HashMap<>();

        if (root != null) {
            for (Object obj : root.getJSONArray("users")) {
                JSONObject json = (JSONObject)obj;

                User user = new User();
                user.setId(json.getLong("id"));
                user.setEmail(json.getString("email"));
                user.setName(json.getString("name"));
                user.setSecondName(json.getString("secondName"));
                user.setId(json.getInt("age"));
                user.setPassword(json.getString("password"));

                users.put(user.getId(), user);
            }
        }

        return users;
    }

    public static void saveUsers(Path path, Map<Long, User> users) throws IOException {
        JSONObject root = Optional.ofNullable(readRootObject(path)).orElseGet(JSONObject::new);
        root.put("users", users.values());

        try (Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
            writer.write(root.toString(2));
        }
    }

    private static JSONObject readRootObject(Path path) throws IOException {
        if (!Files.isReadable(path))
            return null;

        try (Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
            return new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(reader));
        }
    }

    public static void signUp(Map<Long, User> users) {
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            User user = new User();
            System.out.print("Enter age: ");
            user.setAge(scan.nextInt());

            if (user.getAge() < 18)
                throw new RuntimeException("You must be more than 18 years old.");

            System.out.print("Enter email: ");
            user.setEmail(scan.next());

            System.out.print("Enter name: ");
            user.setName(scan.next());

            System.out.print("Enter second name: ");
            user.setSecondName(scan.next());

            System.out.print("Enter password: ");
            user.setPassword(scan.next());

            user.setId(System.nanoTime());
            users.put(user.getId(), user);
        }
    }

}
```